# UWP ScrollViewer.TopHeader with SkiaSharp does not drawing

Tags: c#, uwp, skiasharp

The I want to use the SkiaSharp Canvas in ScrollViewer, but not only in Main content, but in TopHeader and LeftHeader as well.  The paint events are called, the skia is drawing, but the result does not displayed on the screen, just in a main content.

here is the example:

```
<ScrollViewer
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
    <ScrollViewer.TopHeader>
        <Grid
            Width="{Binding ElementName=Canvas, Path=ActualWidth}"
            Height="30"
            Background="LightGray">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
            <skia:SKXamlCanvas
                x:Name="TopHeaderCanvas"
                Margin="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                PaintSurface="OnPaintTopHeader" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer.TopHeader>
    <ScrollViewer.LeftHeader>
        <skia:SKXamlCanvas
            Width="60"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=Canvas, Path=ActualHeight}"
            Background="Gray"
            PaintSurface="OnPaintLeftHeader" />
    </ScrollViewer.LeftHeader>
    <ScrollViewer.Content>
        <skia:SKXamlCanvas
            x:Name="Canvas"
            Width="4000"
            Height="3500"
            Margin="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            PaintSurface="OnPaintMainContent" />
    </ScrollViewer.Content>
</ScrollViewer>
```

As You can see, I tried the skia sharp canvas in wrapped in grid, directly under the ScrollViewer. Unfortunately it does not help.

Here is the result.
[image]

The left is totally empty, but is should be filled with HotPink, and the TopHeader just displays the Grid with "hello" , but it should be covered by canvas, and filled with Green color.

Anybody has an idea, why the skia is not working in ScrollView TopHeader and Left Header?

The SkiaSharp nuget which contains the canvas:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.Views/1.68.2-preview.21

And here are some SkiaSharp example:
https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/master/samples/Basic/UWP/SkiaSharpSample

Comment: could share more about `SKXamlCanvas` control, I could not find related nuget package that could used in uwp platform.

Comment: The question is edited, and add some info, links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug In SkiaSharp.
It is fixed: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/pull/1133

Thank you: [mattleibow](https://github.com/mattleibow)

Answer (score 0):

> UWP ScrollViewer.TopHeader with SkiaSharp does not drawing

I could reproduce your issue, and I tried to re-draw canvas within `PaintSurface` but it also does not work, please feel free post this issue in [`SkiaSharp`](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues) github, And I will report this to the team.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is added: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/1118 The Anser is not accepted, becuse the issue is not solved yet. Thx for understanding